# Function "fwrite" writes unexpected record

Tags: c, file-io, struct

Can anyone please help me correcting the following code?

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char another='Y';
    struct emp
    {
        char name[40];
        int age;
        float bs; //basic salary
    }e;
    fp=fopen("Employee.DAT","wb");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(another=='Y')
    {
        printf("\nEnter name, age and basic salary:");
        scanf("%s %d %f",e.name,&e.age,&e.bs);
        fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp);

        printf("Add another record?(Y/N)");
        fflush(stdin);
        another=getche();
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to input following records into file "Employee.DAT":
`Abc 19 12345
Def 20 12345`
But I'm getting an expected output in the file "Employee.DAT" as in the image attached below: [image]
I think the problem is with "fwrite" but I'm unable to find out the problem.

Comment: *How* do you try to look at the file? You do know that it's *binary* and generally not readable as a text file? That it's binary means that the data you write is written in the internal binary format used by the computer, you can't simply open the file in a text file and hope to see the numbers your written as text.

Comment: Oh by the way, don't do `fflush(stdin)`, it's not supported by the C standard.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the file gets created in the folder in which I've saved my program.

Comment: Please do not get the habit of dumping structs this way. You are in for a world of pain when anything changes. New compiler, architecture or modified struct risks breaking the file reading in unintuitive ways.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund As you may have some good information, I don't think your comment will help the OP in any way. What do you mean by 'this way'? What changes should be made to adapt to your intentions? Where is your reference?

Comment: @moffeltje I realize this is OT, but the OP is a student and might benefit from a push towards design. How members of a struct is stored in memory is compiler implementation dependent, and often padded for memory alignment, and storage of "int" and "float" is computer architeture dependent also. Thus comparing the same file written by the same program with the same data at different times can show differences because of "garbage" in the padding, depending on how you initialize the struct. I would sugest defining a known preferably text-based format, like you sugests in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you print `e.name`, `e.age` and `e.bs` before the fwrite? Did it contain the good values? If it did, I suggest you make an output string to first store the variables in the format you want:

```
char output[MAX_OUTPUT_LENGTH];
...code...
scanf("%s %d %f",e.name,&e.age,&e.bs);
sprintf(output, "%s %d %f", e.name,e.age,e.bs);
fwrite(output,1,sizeof(output),fp);
```

Another thing noticed by Joachim: you may want to open your file like so:

```
 fp = fopen("Employee.DAT", "w");
```

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite` is not the correct function to use here. It doesn't have care about formats, struct padding(`e` may have padding) may etc. It will just attempt to write the number of blocks you asked to write.

Use [`fprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) instead if you want formatted file IO (which is what you need based on your expected output).

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp);
```

You ave given parameters in wrong order.

```
fwrite(&e,1,sizeof(e),fp);
```

This is correct order.

Definition is this -

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
```

Comment: It will still write the record since (s)he writes only one record.

Comment: But getting error when trying to write  more than one record .

Comment: Are you sure? I would expect it to "only" be confusing the programmer unless some special case is triggered?

Comment: @SamuelÅslund yes I am sure about it .

Answer (score 0):

If you want a *formatted* output, you can use `fprintf()` to print individual elements. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) for more info.

Also, don't do `fflush(stdin)`. It's  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, the recommended signature of `main()`  is `int main(void)`.